# is innodb_file_per_table recommended with tens of thousands of tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb

innodb_file_per_table is now the default in mySQL, and is our current setting.

We provide a hosting service for a product with ~200 tables. There are thus hundreds to thousands of databases like that. There is also quite a lot of creation/deletion of those databases (demos).

innodb_file_per_table is the default; but we've read a lot to suggest that it should not be used with lots of tables because of the performance issue with keeping lots of files open. At the same time, we've also read suggestions that having all the data/tables in one file causes contention issues (http://www.iheavy.com/2011/07/28/5-ways-to-boost-mysql-scalability/)

What is the current think on innodb_file_per_table now? It's moved to being the default, are there times when performance would be better to have it off rather than on?